# Can't run Python: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1.0.dll

Tags: python

I setup python and tried to run IDLE but Windows gives me an error: `The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1.0.dll is  missing from your computer.` I tried reinstalling Python to fix this problem, but my pc can't install visual studio.

Comment: You must have tried to install 3.5.something because that is when we change both the installer and VC++ version used to compile.  Others have gotten the same message.  If you search the .dll name, you will get multiple hits  3.5 requires Vista or later and cannot  not run if you have XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.Install Windows Updates:
Go to Start - Control Panel - Windows Update
Check for updates
Install all available updates.
After the updates are installed, restart your computer.
After the restart repeat the steps above again until no more updates are available.

1.Download the Visual C++ Redistributable:

2.For Windows 64-bit
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 (64-bit)
For Windows 32-bit
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 (32-bit)

3.Run the vc_redist.x64.exe (64-bit) or vc_redist.x86.exe (32-bit) and select Uninstall
4.Run the .exe again and select Install

Comment: Hi, my computer is not updating so I'm can't installing Visual C++

Comment: What does that mean?then update your windows using windows updates.

Comment: My computer is not do updating :(

Comment: What does it say ?or happens ?

Comment: İt says Continuous updates audited.

Comment: Well you don't have a python/code related problem. You need to install the above softwares somehow and update your PC.Try manually installing the softwares I mentioned .Google and download them.

Comment: Thank you, I'm try manually installing the softwares :).

Comment: Okey. I'm trying :D. I'm new

Comment: I don't know that manual installation of the C++ redistributable is required ( I never did it), but proper update is.  Even that will not work on XP and other old versions of Windows.